# ARM assembly error undefined reference to `a'

Tags: assembly, arm

I am running ARM assembly code to initialize array a. I get the error saying
undefined reference to `a'. I am using gcc to compile
Here is the code

```
.text
.global main
main:
        ldr r0, addr_of_a    // r1 = *a
        mov r1, #0           // Index i
loop:   str r1, [r0]         // a[i] = i
        add r0, r0, r0, lsl #2   // Increment address by 4 bytes
        add r1, r1, #1       // r1 = r1 + 1
        cmp r1, #100
        bne loop
end:
        mov r0, r1
        bx  lr
addr_of_a: .word a
```

Comment: So where _is_ `a` defined? (assuming it's not actually meant to be the constant 0xa) - What you have there is effectively (in C) `int **addr_of_a = &a`, so the linker needs to know the value of the symbol `a` (i.e. its address) in order to initialise the word at `addr_of_a`. Although the code beforehand appears to assume that `addr_of_a` is actually the array itself... it's not really clear what's supposed to be happening here.

Answer (score 1):

As +Notlikethat indicated, your 'a' is not present.

You may add it accordingly like in the examples below:

```
.data
        a:      .asciz  "deadcode\n"
```

or

```
.data
        a:      .word   3,1,4,1,5,9
```